# Input class to my code and change to a .h file C++

Tags: c++, class

I'm kinda newbie in c++ and I wanted to know how do I catch my code and change it in order to have a class and a .h file.

My code works fine but I really need to separate it and I don't know what to put in the .h file and what to leave in .cpp file.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // variáveis da tabela
    char cSquare1('Q');
    char cSquare2('W');
    char cSquare3('E');
    char cSquare4('A');
    char cSquare5('S');
    char cSquare6('D');
    char cSquare7('Z');
    char cSquare8('X');
    char cSquare9('C');
    int iPlayerTurn(1);
    bool bGameOver(true);
    int placar1(0);
    int placar2(0);


    // Titulo
    cout << "JOGO DO GALO" << endl;
    // Jogo

    do {

        // Imprime tabela
        cout << cSquare1 << "|" << cSquare2 << "|" << cSquare3 << endl;
        cout << "-----"<< endl;
        cout << cSquare4 << "|" << cSquare5 << "|" << cSquare6 << endl;
        cout << "-----"<< endl;
        cout << cSquare7 << "|" << cSquare8 << "|" << cSquare9 << endl;

        // O jogador 1 usa x; O jogador 2 usa 0;
        char cPlayerMark;
        if (iPlayerTurn == 1) {
            cPlayerMark = 'x'; //Este x deve ser minúsculo pois se for maísculo entra em conflito com o valor da tabela
        } else {
            cPlayerMark = '0';
        }

        // Jogada nova
        cout << "Vez do jogador " << iPlayerTurn << endl;
        bool bValidMove;
        // Loop até ter uma jogada válida
        do {
            char cNextMove;
            cin >> cNextMove;
            bValidMove = true;

            // Verifica se é uma jogada válida
            if (cNextMove == 'Q' && cSquare1 == 'Q') {
                cSquare1 = cPlayerMark;
            } else if (cNextMove == 'W' && cSquare2 == 'W') {
                cSquare2 = cPlayerMark;
            } else if (cNextMove == 'E' && cSquare3 == 'E') {
                cSquare3 = cPlayerMark;
            } else if (cNextMove == 'A' && cSquare4 == 'A') {
                cSquare4 = cPlayerMark;
            } else if (cNextMove == 'S' && cSquare5 == 'S') {
                cSquare5 = cPlayerMark;
            } else if (cNextMove == 'D' && cSquare6 == 'D') {
                cSquare6 = cPlayerMark;
            } else if (cNextMove == 'Z' && cSquare7 == 'Z') {
                cSquare7 = cPlayerMark;
            } else if (cNextMove == 'X' && cSquare8 == 'X') {
                cSquare8 = cPlayerMark;
            } else if (cNextMove == 'C' && cSquare9 == 'C') {
                cSquare9 = cPlayerMark;
            } else {
                cout << "Jogada Inválida. Tentar de novo." << endl;
                bValidMove = false;
            }
        } while (!bValidMove);

        bGameOver       = false;
        bool bWinGame   = true;

        // Verifica se o jogo chegou ao fim
        if (cSquare1 != 'Q') {
            if (cSquare2 == cSquare1 && cSquare3 == cSquare1) {
                bGameOver = true;
            }
            if (cSquare4 == cSquare1 && cSquare7 == cSquare1) {
                bGameOver = true;
            }
        }
        if (cSquare5 != 'S') {
            if (cSquare1 == cSquare5 && cSquare9 == cSquare5) {
                bGameOver = true;
            }
            if (cSquare2 == cSquare5 && cSquare8 == cSquare5) {
                bGameOver = true;
            }
            if (cSquare4 == cSquare5 && cSquare6 == cSquare5) {
                bGameOver = true;
            }
            if (cSquare3 == cSquare5 && cSquare7 == cSquare5) {
                bGameOver = true;
            }
        }
        if (cSquare9 != 'C') {
            if (cSquare3 == cSquare9 && cSquare6 == cSquare9) {
                bGameOver = true;
            }
            if (cSquare7 == cSquare9 && cSquare8 == cSquare9) {
                bGameOver = true;
            }
        }
        // Verifica se foi um empate
        if (cSquare1 != 'Q' && cSquare2 != 'W' && cSquare3 != 'E' &&
            cSquare4 != 'A' && cSquare5 != 'S' && cSquare6 != 'D' &&
            cSquare7 != 'Z' && cSquare8 != 'X' && cSquare9 != 'C' && !bGameOver)
        {
            bGameOver = true;
            bWinGame = false;
        }

        if (bGameOver) {

            // Imprime tabela final
            cout << cSquare1 << "|" << cSquare2 << "|" << cSquare3 << endl;
            cout << "-+-+-"<< endl;
            cout << cSquare4 << "|" << cSquare5 << "|" << cSquare6 << endl;
            cout << "-+-+-"<< endl;
            cout << cSquare7 << "|" << cSquare8 << "|" << cSquare9 << endl;

            if (bWinGame) {
                cout << "O jogador " << iPlayerTurn << " venceu!" << endl;
                // Incrementa as vitórias no placar
                if(iPlayerTurn == 1){
                    placar1++;

                } else if(iPlayerTurn == 2){
                    placar2++;
                }
            }

            else {
                cout << "Houve um empate!" << endl;
            }

            cout << "Fim do jogo!" << endl;
            cout << "Jogar de novo? (S/N)?" << endl;
            char cPlayAgain;
            cin >> cPlayAgain;

            if (cPlayAgain == 'S') {
                bGameOver = false;
                // Limpa a tabela - volta aos valores iniciais
                cSquare1 = 'Q';
                cSquare2 = 'W';
                cSquare3 = 'E';
                cSquare4 = 'A';
                cSquare5 = 'S';
                cSquare6 = 'D';
                cSquare7 = 'Z';
                cSquare8 = 'X';
                cSquare9 = 'C';
            }
            else if (cPlayAgain == 'N') {
                bGameOver = true;
                // Mostra o sumário dos resultados
                cout << "Sumário dos resultados:" << endl;
                cout << "Jogador 1: " << placar1 << endl;
                cout << "Jogador 2: " << placar2 << endl;
            }

            iPlayerTurn = 1;
        } else {
            // Vez dos jogadores
            if (iPlayerTurn == 1) {
                iPlayerTurn = 2;
            } else {
                iPlayerTurn = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (!bGameOver);
}
```

Comment: since you don't have any structure or procedures in your code, there is nothing to put in a *.h.

Comment: "catch" code? But really, if this is the entire code, there is nothing to separate (all of the code is in `main`). What would benefit from separating the code would be to make small functions and/or classes to do the work, and `main` just uses those. *Then* it makes sense to worry about putting in multiple files.

Comment: First... break it up into methods (functions).  Find things that seem like logical units (or better re-useable units) and put those outside of main().  Once you've done that you can start to think about moving something into a header that might be useful to another module.  PS - Game loops can be notoriously difficult to compartmentalize.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, if you have a class, leave the definition of the class (private members, maybe constructor(s) and destructor) and methods' prototypes in a header file, and put the methods' definitions in a separate .cpp file. (Don't forget to include the header in the .cpp file.)

But you don't have a class, actually, you just have `main()`... 
Maybe you could try making functions to do what you're doing in `main()` right now - for example, check if a valid move was made or if the game ended (prototypes in .h, definitions in .cpp) and just call them when you need them.

In case you don't want to make your code more *object-oriented* and write classes and methods, I don't really think modularisation makes much sense; in case you do - the answer above explains how you would do that really nicely :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to break up your program into classes, here are some suggestions:

**Board class**
This class manages the board, including moving pieces, initialization and displaying.

**Player class**
This would represent a player and the interactions between the board, I/O and and other players.

**Game Engine class**
This class provides the "glue" between players, the board and other resources (such as the screen or windows).

Your program is small enough that you can experiment easily with extracting functionality into classes (objects).

Without classes, I would only break up a program if it is too long and it can be split up into identifiable themes.  The themes or main program should warrant refactoring only if the pieces don't need to change often or isolating one or pieces protect the other pieces from changes.